# Show most rated objects. Letsrate, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problem. I want to show the best hotels on page 5, but I do not know how to do it. I maintenance used gem letsrate.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "hotels", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "author"
    t.boolean  "breakfast"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.integer  "address_id"
  end

  create_table "rates", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "rater_id"
    t.integer  "rateable_id"
    t.string   "rateable_type"
    t.float    "stars",         null: false
    t.string   "dimension"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rates", ["rateable_id", "rateable_type"], name: "index_rates_on_rateable_id_and_rateable_type"
  add_index "rates", ["rater_id"], name: "index_rates_on_rater_id"

  create_table "rating_caches", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "cacheable_id"
    t.string   "cacheable_type"
    t.float    "avg",            null: false
    t.integer  "qty",            null: false
    t.string   "dimension"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "rating_caches", ["cacheable_id", "cacheable_type"], name: "index_rating_caches_on_cacheable_id_and_cacheable_type"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

**rate.rb**

```
class Rate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rater, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :rateable, :polymorphic => true

  #attr_accessible :rate, :dimension

end
```

**hotel.rb**

```
class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :address
  letsrate_rateable 'Rating'
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  letsrate_rater
  has_many :hotels

end
```

**Please**

I know how to do this using sql query, but I just started learning RoR and I'm sure there are more elegant way that someone can suggest?

Comment: Post the sql query then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to change the dimension name to be downcased, otherwise it wouldn't map to your table names and the uppecase relation names this gem generated wouldn't follow rails conventions.

```
#Hotel
letsrate_rateable 'rating'
```

To show top n hotels by rating, run

```
Hotel.includes(:rating_average).order("rating_caches.avg DESC").limit(n)
```

You have to also add an index to the `avg` field in `rating_caches`

Have also a look on [letsrate_rateable](https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate/blob/master/lib/letsrate/model.rb#L95) method. It just defines some associations based on the dimnesion names

Comment: Thanks, but I have error "Direction should be :asc or :desc"
@hotels_rate = Hotel.includes(:rating_average).order(rating_average: {avg: :desc}).limit(5)

Comment: You have to also add an index to the avg field in rating_caches. How do this? 
add_references?

Comment: create a new migration `rails g migration AddIndexToRatingCaches` then  within change block call `add_index :rating_caches, :avg`

Comment: i see... then there is no ower way as using some sql fragement within order. See update

Comment: Still much better than raw sql :)

Comment: Hotel.includes(:rating_average).order("rating_average.avg DESC").limit(n), mb rating_cahes.avg?